# How do I target the correct data attribute and child element when dealing will multiple occurrences of the same parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom slider element. I want to render many slider elements in the same page but the problem I have is that the dynamic CSS styling targets common attribute names thus if I have two elements `#sliderA` and `#sliderB`, the changes that should happen to `#sliderB` happen to `sliderA` instead.

I suppose I require JavaScript to target the `data-freq` attribute of the respective slider element.

https://codepen.io/ryanvb92/pen/poNLQEO

As you can guess, I'm working with someone else's pen. Here is the [original pen](https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/Zqjdmg).

Comment: have u tried unique ID for every slider and have css based on slider ID

Comment: But I want the same functionality for every ```.custom-slider```. Wouldn't using CSS require me to constantly update the CSS file every time I add a new instance of the element or am I missing something?

Comment: Your question is confusing. In the question you say you want to have `#sliderA` and `#sliderB` be different, but your pen doesn't include those IDs. Also in the comment you want to have them be the same? What is it different or the same?

Comment: BTW the id `form-title` is duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css is pretty straight forward

```
input {
        &:checked {
            + label::after {
                border-width: 4px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.75);
            }
  ....
```

The above rule is used to style a checked input and is working as expected. The only problem is that you are providing same `id` to multiple `input` tags.

```
  <input type="radio" name="smokingFreq" id="1" value="1" required>
        
  <input type="radio" name="drinkingFreq" id="1" value="1" required>
```

Notice how input elements are sharing same id across different sliders. Duplicating ids is strictly avoided because browser expects them to be unique throughout the document.

Just use unique ids for all inputs. Something like this should fix your issue.

```
  <input type="radio" name="smokingFreq" id="smokingFreq-1" value="1" required>

  <input type="radio" name="drinkingFreq" id="drinkingFreq-1" value="1" required>
```

Comment: Yes, careless mistake of mine. However, the problem still isn't resolve as the CSS seems to depend on an integer id.

Comment: there is no such dependency in the css rule. When you update the name of your input, you would need to update the `for` field of the corresponding label too. It should work then.

Comment: Silly me. Forgot to update the ```for```. Thanks, it's working fine now!